# How to Auth from an external service to the bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have an external service with is own database where the users can log in.

Now I have a bot in NodeJS using Bot Builder and the Bot Framework.

I want to link them.

Is there anyway that the bot recognize the users from the other service everytime they open a new conversation and everytime they write something in the bot?

I've just tried with web chat before and I know that with channels that they support like Facebook, Telegram, Skype etc is easy to recognize the users every time they come back, but I don't know how if it is possible to do this with an external service where the users are already logged in and they want to talk with the chatbot.

I don't know how could I generate an authtoken or something that the bot framework read it and recognize the user.

Comment: If your channel is web chat, you can try to consider to use The Backchannel to pass the username & password when user open the bot. refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DirectLine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to allow your bot and a custom client to communicate to each other, a sample can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine), and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets) if you want to use WebSockets.

You can also add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service to use OAuth as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), where you will find samples too.